# heroku request timeout parse

Tags: xcode, heroku, parse-platform

I migrated my app to heroku + mlab from parse. I would too often get request timeout error on the logs. I turned on verbose and below is what i get when a timeout happens:

```
2016-05-25T15:27:40.946050+00:00 app[web.1]: [36mverbose[39m: POST /parse/events/AppOpened { host: 'dairy-oneandahalf.herokuapp.com',

2016-05-25T15:27:40.946067+00:00 app[web.1]:   connection: 'close',

2016-05-25T15:27:40.946074+00:00 app[web.1]:   'x-parse-app-build-version': '1',

2016-05-25T15:27:40.946084+00:00 app[web.1]:     "__type": "Date"

2016-05-25T15:27:41.517425+00:00 app[web.1]: [36mverbose[39m: GET /parse/classes/_User { host: 'dairy-oneandahalf.herokuapp.com',

2016-05-25T15:27:41.517436+00:00 app[web.1]:   connection: 'close',

2016-05-25T15:27:41.517445+00:00 app[web.1]:   'x-parse-client-version': 'i1.13.0',

2016-05-25T15:27:41.517448+00:00 app[web.1]:   'x-forwarded-for': '58.152.243.212',

2016-05-25T15:27:40.948269+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/parse/events/AppOpened" host=dairy-oneandahalf.herokuapp.com request_id=3e9b1390-a1b8-487b-8229-f4c44777b2a4 fwd="58.152.243.212" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=6ms status=200 bytes=483

2016-05-25T15:28:12.746545+00:00 app[web.1]: [36mverbose[39m: GET /parse/classes/allPosts { host: 'dairy-oneandahalf.herokuapp.com',

2016-05-25T15:28:12.746591+00:00 app[web.1]:   connection: 'close',

2016-05-25T15:28:12.746600+00:00 app[web.1]:   'x-request-id': '84c7c271-4725-42c2-a111-3cf8e2c16d52',

2016-05-25T15:28:12.746602+00:00 app[web.1]:   'total-route-time': '0',

2016-05-25T15:28:12.746605+00:00 app[web.1]:         "query": {

2016-05-25T15:28:11.513492+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=POST path="/parse/classes/_User" host=dairy-oneandahalf.herokuapp.com request_id=1260ec0f-3cee-4c43-a87e-9146ef154e29 fwd="58.152.243.212" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30001ms status=503 bytes=0
```

I'm very new to heroku, can somebody explain to me what is wrong and what I can do about solving it? any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance